# Repeating function call inside a while loop

Tags: c++, while-loop

I have a function called `move()` which I placed inside a while loop. This function lets the user choose an integer from 1 to 4 and returns that number. The while loop exits the loop if the function returns 3 or 4. This is my code in the main function.

```
while(move() < 3){
    if(move() == 2){
        cout << "You hate this fruit: ";
    }
    cout << "Enter name of fruit: ";
    cin >> fruit;
    cout << endl;
}
```

My problem is when I run the program, if I chose 1 or 2, the function move() will be called once again before proceeding with the rest of the code. How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assign the result of `move()` to a variable, so you can use it more than once.

```
int m;
while ((m = move()) < 3) {
    if (m == 2) {
    // and so on
```

or, according to taste

```
for (int m = move(); m < 3; m = move()) {
    if (m == 2) {
    // and so on
```

Comment: Thanks! I forgot that I could assign a function to a variable.